# extjs grid footer totals... summary showing multiple times

Tags: extjs, grid

I am trying to add a summary footer to my extjs project.  For some reason I am getting a funky response visually... it seems to be added separate rows with totals.  In my example there are only 2 rows of actual data... but it seems to be added 3 rows of footers.  To add more details... when I look at the grid before I load the data (which should be a blank grid), I see two totals rows with a zero value.  Does anyone know how to fix this?

Data is added with store.load

[image: screenshot]

[image]

```
                            xtype: 'grid',
                        title: 'Portfolio Level',
                        itemId: 'performancePortfolioLevelGridID',
                        bind: {
                            store: '{myPortfolioPerformanceStore}'
                        },
                        margin: '10px 0px 10px 0px',
                        ui: 'featuredpanel-framed',
                        cls: 'custom-gridPerformance',
                        height: 600,
                        width: 975,
                        collapsible: false,
                        features: [{
                            ftype: 'summary'
                        }],
columns:[
{
                                header: 'Gross P&L - Daily',
                                dataIndex: 'dailyGrossPl',
                                renderer: function (value) {
                                    var newVal;
                                    var calc = value.toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                                    if (value > 0) {
                                        newVal = '<span style="color:green">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                                    } else if (value < 0) {
                                        newVal = '<span style="color:red">' + "$" + calc + '</span>';
                                    } else {
                                        newVal = "$" + calc;
                                    }
                                    return newVal;
                                },
                                align: 'right',
                                flex: 1,
                                summaryType: 'sum'
}
```

Comment: Are you programmatically adding records to this store?
Can you create a Sencha Fiddle with your code and replicate this issue to be able to better understand the issue?
What version of Ext JS are you using?

Comment: yes, I am programmically adding records to this store with store.load.  Also using extjs6.  not sure how to use fiddle... let me check.  Is the cause the way I add records?

Comment: 1. Can you tell the exact version by checking Ext.versions.ext.version in your browser console?
2. You can create a Sencha Fiddle here (https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor )and save it and share the url. This will bring some clarity into this issue.
3. Posting more code may help anyone looking here present a clear suggestion.
4. If you remove the rendered does the issue exist?
5. If you remove the summary 'features' does the issue exist?

Comment: sure... how do I find it in my browser console?

Comment: Open browser, 
Load ur application url, 
Press F12/ Open Developer Tools, 
In Console Tab, Enter Ext.versions.ext.version and press enter.

Comment: thanks... "6.0.0.640"

Comment: features: [{
 ftype: 'summary',
 dock: 'bottom'
}],

can you try adding dock bottom?

Comment: UNBELIEVABLE... all I was missing was the dock: bottom.  THANKS SO MUCH... WORKS NOW!!!

Comment: still working on fiddle just so I can show my issues in the future better